# SQL - Difference of column

Tags: mysql, sql

Im new to this SQL thing and I need some help, because I just cannot move any further with my project.

I have 3 tables with a list of users, itmes and a relation between them. User can have an item (1) or not (0), or can have a dublicate (0/1).

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_no varchar(255),
    item_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  dup tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

How can I list out the items where the user doesn't have those items, but others have duplicates of it?

So far I can list out the duplicate items what other users have, but I can't remove the ones that the user already have:

```
SELECT 
t3.user_id AS 'User_ID',
t1.username AS 'Username',
GROUP_CONCAT(t3.item_id ORDER BY t3.item_id ASC) AS 'Item List'
from table3 t3
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id=t3.item_id
inner join accounts t1 on t1.id=t3.user_id
WHERE user_id != 17 AND t3.dup = 1
group by t3.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT('Item_List') DESC;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: Sure! I hope this will do: https://pastebin.com/GnSwzvds

Comment: Please don’t add links to images or external sites - add all information to your question as editable text. The only exception should be if you create a dbfiddle for your question - then you can link to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `inner join` to join data with the list of missing items can do the trick.

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is to concat items grouped by user_id.

```
select max(t1.user_name) as user_name , group_concat(t2.item_name separator ', ') as item_no
from table3 t3
inner join table1 t1 on t3.user_id = t1.id
inner join table2 t2 on t3.item_id = t2.id
inner join (
  select t3.*
  from table3 t3
  where user_id = 1 and stat = 0
) as c on t3.item_id = c.item_id 
where t3.dup = 1
group by t1.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UqFotiMI)